# Graphs in a loop in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a graph that works outside of a loop, but when it is included in a loop, I get the message "running inline gpl" and the error message "GPL error: id('graphdataset') not a quoted string: 'graphdataset'." Is there a special way to run graphs in a loop that I am missing?

```
DEFINE !ess1 (inum=!charend ('/') 
/ iname=!charend ('/')
/ iname2=!charend ('/')
/ g1=!charend ('/')
/ g2=!charend ('/')
/ g3=!charend ('/')
/ g4=!charend ('/')).

RECODE INST 
    (!inum=1) 
    ( !g1 = 2) 
    (!g2= 3)    
    (!g3=4)
    (!g4=5)
    into cgroup.
MISSING VALUES cgroup(-9).
variable labels cgroup 'Comparison Group'.
value labels cgroup 1 !iname2 2 'Thing1' 3 'Thing2' 4 'Thing3' 5 'Thing4'.
EXECUTE.

USE ALL.
VARIABLE LEVEL ALL (NOMINAL).

CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=satisf cgroup DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE cgroup  [ROWPCT.COUNT PCT40.1] BY satisf
  /SLABELS VISIBLE=NO
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=satisf cgroup ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES LABEL="Overall" POSITION=AFTER
  MISSING=EXCLUDE
  /TITLES
   TITLE= 'Overall, how satisfied have you been with this example syntax?'.

RENAME VARIABLES  (sinstql sdiscus sadvising sadmresp ssoclife scampcom slivecom=Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7). 

varstocases
/make Likert From Var1 to Var7
/index Question (Likert).

*I need to make a variable to panel by.
compute panel = 0.
if Likert > 2 panel = 1.

*Aggregate N per question.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
/BREAK Question
/TotalPerQ = N.

*Use trans to make a percent.
GGRAPH
/GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Question MEAN(TotalPerQ)[name="MeanTotalPerQ"] COUNT()[name="COUNT"] Likert panel
MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
/GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
COORD: transpose(mirror(rect(dim(1,2))))
DATA: Question=col(source(s), name("Question"), unit.category())
DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT"))
DATA: MeanTotalPerQ=col(source(s), name("MeanTotalPerQ"))
DATA: Likert=col(source(s), name("Likert"), unit.category())
DATA: panel=col(source(s), name("panel"), unit.category())
TRANS: Perc = eval((COUNT/MeanTotalPerQ)*100)
GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Satisfaction"))
GUIDE: axis(dim(3), null(), gap(0px))
GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), null())
SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), sort.values("1","2","4","3"), map(("1", color.red), ("2", color.lightpink), ("3", color.lightgreen), ("4", color.green)))
ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(Question*Perc*panel), color.interior(Likert),shape.interior(shape.square),transparency.exterior(transparency."1"))
END GPL.
******************************.

dataset close *.

get file= 'FilePath.sav'.

DELETE VARIABLES cgroup.

OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS  EXPORT=VISIBLE  LAYERS=PRINTSETTING  MODELVIEWS=PRINTSETTING
  /PDF  DOCUMENTFILE=!Quote(!Concat('Y:\Surveys\ESS\2015\COFHE ESS 2015 Comparison Report ',!iname,'.pdf'))
     EMBEDBOOKMARKS=YES  EMBEDFONTS=YES.

OUTPUT SAVE
OUTFILE=!Quote(!Concat('Y:\Surveys\ESS\2015\COFHE ESS 2015 Comparison Report ',!iname,'.spv'))

OUTPUT CLOSE *. 
OUTPUT NEW.

!ENDDEFINE.

!ess1 inum=1/iname=Name1/ iname2='Name1'/g1= 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
!ess1 inum=2 /iname=Name2 /iname2='Name2'/g1= 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
!ess1 inum=3 /iname=Name3 /iname2='Name3'/g1= 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using macros? You could also make use of the Python-Plugin (run the whole syntax inside of a Python loop).

Comment: Hi Mirirai, I have edited my code above for brevity, with my graph syntax in the code that throws the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are not supported with GPL, because the GPL syntax doesn't follow standard SPSS Statistics syntax and macro expansion would be unreliable.  Sometimes it would work, but Python programmability is the appropriate mechanism for this.

A demonstration on how to do this can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ab16c38e-2f7b-4912-a47e-85682d124d32/entry/how_can_i_parameterize_ggraph_and_gpl_code6?lang=en)